# Setting UIAlertView button's color in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

i'm a new swift programmer and i need to change the color of my UIAlertView's button's color. for example i want to change the UIColor of that to yellow. can you help me please?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `tintColor` like so:

```
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

But customizing a `UIAlertView` is frowned upon by Apple.

> The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

[**UIAlertView Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

There are [alternatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20alert%20view%20github&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=custom%20uialertview%20github) though.