# UIAlertAction with style UIAlertActionStyleDestructive color from Red to Grey when disabled iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertaction

I can't change my `UIAlertAction`'s `UIAlertActionStyleDestructive` color from red to grey when the action is disabled.

Setting the `UIAlertAction` to disabled on iOS 9 changes the color to grey. On iOS 8 the color remains red.

Comment: There's a `tintColor` property that will allow you to set the color. [Setting UIAlertView button's color in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30738097/2108547).

Comment: @DanielStorm  can I just tinColor the UIAlertActionStyleDestructive UIAlertAction and keep the bule color of the  UIAlertActionStyleNormal ones? let me have a try.

Comment: @JerryZhou you can do that, but only if you use a private API, which is not recommended

Comment: @kabiroberai, actually disable UIAlertAction of  UIAlertActionStyleDestructive  will change the color from Red to Grey on iOS9,  it's just different on iOS8.

Comment: @JerryZhou I ran into this issue too (iOS 8.3), the weird thing is that the button is technically disabled but the color is still colored as if it were enabled.

Comment: @ajfigueroa, yes, and iOS9 is fine.

Comment: @JerryZhou Did you ever resolve this issue? If so, we should file a radar report for this. I think this might be an iOS 8 bug :(

Comment: @ajfigueroa NO, not resolved.

Comment: @ajfigueroa And I don't have the chance to test on the last iOS8 version which is pre version before update to iOS9. Just not sure with that version.