# How to change the style of AlertController Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Hello I want to change the alert style, where the color of the whole text is white, the bottom of the alert is trasnparente (**backgroundColor that is clear.**) and the buttons tambine white color.

[That's how I got it, And i do not want it that way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdBlX.png)

[That's how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKLdC.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting UIAlertView button's color in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737983/setting-uialertview-buttons-color-in-swift)

Comment: I commented on the first answer. I believe what you want is **not** a *button* color - like @DanielStorm suggests - but an **backgroundColor** that is clear. If that's correct, you should put that in your *question*. (Please, not in your comments.) If that's what you want, I do not believe it's possible. I wish it were, and will remove my answer down vote (I didn't down vote your question) along with all my comments once I see how it's possible.

Comment: @JoseTovar, please look for a comment from "matt" in the answer below. That link will provide you with the code - if you are working with Swift 3, you'll need to convert the code, but it's straightforward.

Comment: hi,I want the background to be transparent following the demo of matt the background is still white

Comment: Yes, but a one line change will make it transparent. Trust me, the code works.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. I could do the effect I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to create a custom alert controller for this behaviour. I would start by subclassing UIView, then layout your subviews accordingly

Comment: Will that work? While the question didn't specifically ask this, the images **clearly** show that the background color is *clear*. Not only are warnings thrown with this - it simply doesn't work out of box. I'm down voting your answer, even though I'm looking for the same thing. Can you explain in a bit  more detail? Perhaps some code? (Trust me, if you have something that works, I'll immediately up vote it.)

Comment: I think theres been some confusion by what I mean what I say custom controller. I don't mean subclasses, I mean creating your own completely separate to UIAlertController.

Comment: And...? What are you subclassing from UIKit? UIViewController? NSObject? Yes, I'm confused. And for such "depth" needed to do this, how is this an answer? It works better as a comment I think.

Comment: Its depends on how you want to implement it. Theres no "this is the way to do it" answer. Also it's not a small task, so providing code is not simple. I would start by subclassing UIView, then layout your subviews accordingly.

Comment: @Welton122 Your last comment is a good reason why you should post this as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @dfd see https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 This shows how to make your own presented view controller that behaves just like an alert. After all, an alert _is_ a presented view controller, so why not roll your own? Now you can make it look however you like.

Comment: @matt, once again, thank you. About a week ago I was looking for *exactly* something like this. I'm going to spend the next hour digesting how you did this.

Comment: @Welton122, see my last comment above. I still think you should provide a *bit* more detail, but as pointed out in the GitHub link, it works. Hopefully the OP will see this and make use of it. As promised, my down-vote is now an up-vote.